# CSS Font-Family Support Dropped for <SELECT> in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, drop-down-menu, fonts

The following CSS used to work in all browsers that I have tested. It even has an option selector to handle Firefox.

```css
select,
option {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>PN-2345&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The first element&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hardware</option>
  <option>Pn-1332-CFG&nbsp;&nbsp;Second thing&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Powdercoat</option>
</select>
```

The newest versions of Firefox no longer properly apply font family styles.
Former versions of Firefox, and every other major browser I've tested, fully apply the font family settings both to the select and to the items in the dropdown - now, it only gets applied to the select box itself, but NOT the dropdown.

[image: Select box with partial support for the font (here shown in Impact). Note the items are not showing the proper font.]

Does Firefox still support font-family changes to dropdowns? If so, how?

Comment: it does work here (MacOS 10.11.6, Firefox 49.0.1)

Comment: @Johannes Perhaps it's specific to Windows? Both myself and my client are experiencing the issue. Just to be sure, you hit the dropdown to check if the <option> items are properly styled as well?

Comment: Yes, i did that - it works here

Comment: @Johannes Thanks for the info!

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1141257 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022 - It's real!!

Comment: The bug is still present in Firefox 61. I submitted [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1471238) in Bugzilla.

Comment: For me it shows with styles only for select but not for options.

screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/JR19hfB.png

Windows 10, firefox 66.0.2

Comment: Bug present in Ubuntu 20, Firefox: 82.0 (64-Bit)

Answer (score 11):

I did some experiments, and apparently the font-family will render correctly in `<option>` elements as long as the font is installed locally. Which is obviously useless.

If anyone has any info disproving me, please tell us.

Comment: It seems you are correct and it will only show the font if it is installed locally. All you can do is make the font stack as good as possible, so you atleast have a decent fallback font.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the font for both the select and option elements in Firefox using:

```
select, option {
  font: -moz-pull-down-menu;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did the opposite of what I wanted. I've got a dropdown in Firefox that the menu is the correct font, but the dropdown options are different. But now instead of applying the CSS `font-family` property from my stylesheet to the `options` it is also removed from the menu entirely!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work? You can use this code if you want to :)

```js
var ff = document.getElementById('sel');

function font() {
  ff.style.fontFamily = "'" + ff.value + "', sans-serif";
}
```

```css
select {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}

option#diff {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

option#muli {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

option#over {
  font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli:wght@300&family=Overpass:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<select id='sel' onchange='font()'>
  <option id='muli' value='Muli'>Muli yay</option>
  <option selected id='over' value='Overpass'>Overpass hooray</option>
  <option id='diff' value='Ubuntu'>Ubuntu is awesome</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope, the snippet presents the same error in Firefox =(

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Firefox delegates the rendering of options to the OS to some extent, so only fonts that are installed on the system can be applied. You can mitigate this for most cases by setting a fallback font or at least a generic family, like the code in the question does with `, monospace` at the end of the rule. That's how I interpret [this comment from bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1536148#c19).

Answer (score -4):

```
-moz-font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it