# HTML select option text monospace

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get select options to use monospace fonts so that they are lined up vertically when you click the drop down.  I am trying to put a code left justified followed by a dash and then a description.  I added the options using coded spaces so that each option has the same number of characters before the dash, but they still are not lined up.  I tried courier new and monospace.  I can tell it is using the fonts because they change, but they are still not lined up.  Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>font test</title>
 <style>
 select, option{
  font-family:monospace, monospace;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <select name=SOURCECODE>
   <option value="" selected>Select a Option</option>
   <option value="A">A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST A</option>
   <option value="AB">AB&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST AB</option>
   <option value="ABC">ABC&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST ABC</option>
   <option value="ABCD">ABCD&nbsp;- TEST ABCD</option>
   <option value="A">A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST A</option>
   <option value="AB">AB&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST AB</option>
   <option value="ABC">ABC&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST ABC</option>
   <option value="ABCD">ABCD&nbsp;- TEST ABCD</option>
  </select>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to make this work?

****Note this appears to only be a problem with firefox

Comment: Seems to look fine in Chrome

Comment: You should consider `<optgroup>`.

Comment: I believe this won't work in all browsers. The best solution would be creating a custom select so you can use custom font families.

Comment: The optgroup would not be a solution because each has its own option.  I did what I did based on research and could not get it to work, but was using FF.  I tried it in chrome and it works fine as fine, also in IE.  if anyone has a solution for FF, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, reading throught several articles, it seems that this is a Mozilla Firefox's bug, and the font style cannot actually be set at the moment (as of 10.5.2018). I have personally tested on `59.0.2` and `60.0` on Windows 10 (x64), both have the same bug.

- 5 years old bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022
- 11 months old bug report (for BG color): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1376443
- SO question on the same topic: [CSS Font-Family Support Dropped for <SELECT> in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884774/css-font-family-support-dropped-for-select-in-firefox)

I have also noticed this writting in regards to `option` tag:

> Firefox refuses to apply background-color to option tag on a select menu.
>
> Problem encountered since Firefox 48 and +, on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 (all x64)
>
> Problem not encontered on Firefox 48 and +, on Windows XP 32 bits

---

Solutions that would usually work (but not working in this case):

- changing font-family to monospace
- adding tabs (`&#9;`) and `<pre></pre>` tags
- as Kelvin Samuel noted, creating own custom Select might work (e.g. following [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp), see below working solution)

---

**Working custom select from tutorial:**

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
 /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!--surround the select box within a "custom-select" DIV element.
Remember to set the width:-->
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
   <option value="" selected>Select a Option</option>
   <option value="A">A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST A</option>
   <option value="AB">AB&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST AB</option>
   <option value="ABC">ABC&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST ABC</option>
   <option value="ABCD">ABCD&nbsp;- TEST ABCD</option>
   <option value="A">A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST A</option>
   <option value="AB">AB&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST AB</option>
   <option value="ABC">ABC&nbsp;&nbsp;- TEST ABC</option>
   <option value="ABCD">ABCD&nbsp;- TEST ABCD</option>
  </select>
</div>
```