# CSS font-face rule not rendered on select option in Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-select

I created a custom `font-face`, which works fine on the closed down `select`. But on the expanded `option` elements it is not rendered.

Testing in Firefox, Chrome is working fine.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'code';
  src: local('Consolas');
}

select {
  font-family: 'code';
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>foo</option>
</select>
```

---

Update: I should add that when not using `@font-face` but only setting

```
select {
  font-family: Consolas
}
```

it works also for the options

Comment: I think you can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102955/html-select-option-text-monospace